# How to call H2 LINK_SCHEMA?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, h2

I'm trying to run [link_schema](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#link_schema)

```
    final String query = "? = CALL LINK_SCHEMA('ROADS', '', '" + url + "', '" + user + "', '" + pass + "', 'ROADS');";
    CallableStatement statement = conn.prepareCall(query);
    statement.execute();
    ResultSet rs = statement.getResultSet();
```

I'm getting a `ResultSet` but it doesn't contain the list of tables as promised. Also later when I try to access a table I get the error "Schema not found". Where did I go wrong?

Update: The problem seems to be the Oracle driver; check the answer and comment section by [Evgenij Ryazanov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58624143/480894).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```sql
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("CALL LINK_SCHEMA(…)");
```

or more secure and safe

```sql
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("CALL LINK_SCHEMA(?, '', ?, ?, ?, ?)");
ps.setString(1, "ROADS");
ps.setString(2, url);
ps.setString(3, user);
ps.setString(4, pass);
ps.setString(5, "ROADS");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Simple test case:

```java
try (Connection c1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:1");
        Connection c2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:2")) {
    Statement s1 = c1.createStatement(), s2 = c2.createStatement();
    s1.execute("CREATE SCHEMA S; CREATE TABLE S.T1(ID INT); CREATE TABLE S.T2(ID INT)");
    try (ResultSet rs = s2.executeQuery("CALL LINK_SCHEMA('S', '', 'jdbc:h2:mem:1', '', '', 'S')")) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }
    }
}
```

```
T1
T2
```

Comment: If you get an exception, you need to post it here. You also need to check that you use a correct URL, source database already exists, has the specified schema (check case of the characters too, `ROADS` and `roads` can be different) and some table(s) in it. How exactly the url looks like?

Comment: `LINK_SCHEMA` does not return an error if schema wasn't found in the specified database, so you need to check its presence by yourself. Try to check content of `ResultSet rs = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass).getMetaData().getTables(null, "ROADS", null, null)`.

Comment: url I'm using for connection:
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<hostname>)(PORT=<port number>)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=<service name)))";

Comment: Try the command from the comment above with that url and check that `getMetaData().getTables()` returns some rows. H2 executes such command internally and uses table names from `TABLE_NAME` column.

Comment: I did it and get back the tables I expected.

Comment: H2 uses `rs.next()` / `rs.getString("TABLE_NAME")` on that result set from Oracle (or other database). If it returns some normal names H2 should see them too. Download the sources of H2 (from Maven Central, for example), set a breakpoint on `org.h2.table.LinkSchema.linkSchema()`, and check what's going on.

Comment: I did as you told: `getMetaData().getTables()` is returning more than just tables, it is also returning synonyms and the first synonym points to a package. Then H2 tries to run CREATE LINKED TABLE on that package and we get an error.

Comment: H2 has a trick for PostgreSQL and it looks like another trick for Oracle is required. If you don't want to change sources of H2, you need to use `CREATE LINKED TABLE` for each real table https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#create_linked_table as a workaround.

Comment: It seems that H2 is running the following query, so it is fetching the synonyms also:

SELECT NULL AS table_cat,
       o.owner AS table_schem,
       o.object_name AS table_name,
       o.object_type AS table_type,
       NULL AS remarks
  FROM all_objects o
  WHERE o.owner LIKE :1 ESCAPE '/'
    AND o.object_name LIKE :2 ESCAPE '/'
    AND o.object_type IN ('TABLE', 'SYNONYM', 'VIEW')
  ORDER BY table_type, table_schem, table_name

Comment: This query is produced by Oracle's driver in its implementation of `DatabaseMetaData.getTables()`. Hypothetically H2 can use the last parameter of `getTables()` to exclude synonyms, but somebody else may need them. Technically this method shouldn't return synonyms that aren't usable as a table, so it looks more like an issue with Oracle's driver. Just use the separate `CREATE LINKED TABLE` commands instead for all tables that you need.